# How to Convert geoip_country_code() Geoip1 javascript script to Geoip2

Tags: javascript, geoip, maxmind

So I have this piece of code that I would like to convert to Geoip2 :

```
window.onload = function(){

var eu = ['AT','DE','BE','ES','FI','FR','IE','IT','LU','NL','PT','GR','SI','CY','MT','SK','EE'];
var country = geoip_country_code();
var index = eu.indexOf(country);

if(index > -1){

    document.getElementById('prices').src = "http://test.com";  

}else{

    document.getElementById('prices').src = "http://test.com";

}}
```

The problem is at lign 4 : geoip_country_code(); is not working, and by that I mean that it doesn't return anything nor throw an error. I know that it's because this function is not available in geoip2, so I'm looking for a substitute.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Please explain what "not working" means. Does it throw an error? Does it return nothing?

Comment: alright so...what is in the `geoip_country_code` function?

Comment: Its supposed to be a two letters string, like in the eu variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean the maxmind-API:

The new name of the function is `geoip2.country` .

The returned result will contain a `country`-property, the desired value(ISO-code) is available via the `iso_code`-member of the `country`-property:

```
window.onload = function(){
geoip2.country(
  function(result){
    var eu = ['AT','DE','BE','ES','FI','FR','IE','IT','LU','NL','PT','GR','SI','CY','MT','SK','EE'];
    var country = result.country.iso_code;
    var index = eu.indexOf(country);
    if(index > -1){
      document.getElementById('prices').src = "http://test.com?eu=1";  
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById('prices').src = "http://test.com?eu=0";
    }
  },
  function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

For more details see: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/